# DNS configurations to activate PrivateZone on Alibaba Cloud ECS

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I want to activate PrivateZone on Alibaba Cloud ECS instance so that I can create private zones, add records to the private zones and associate the private zones with VPS's.

How can I modify the DNS configurations to activate PrivateZone.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the DNS console activate it clicking **Private Zone** https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/64627.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.10.2c6017cfXo6FnT

You don't need to change anything on your instances, private dns zone should workout of the box. https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/65415.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.b99.23.2c6017cf39XXX6

[image: Activated private zone]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use privatezone you need to activate it. After activating the service add the private zone and configure a record for the zone.

**To add a private zone:**

1. Log on to the **DNS console**
2. Click **ZoneList** and Click **AddZone** add a new zone

You can see that the zone is created.

**To configure a record for the zone:**

1. Select the privatezone and enter into resolution page settings
2. Click **Add Record** to add a record.

Note: You can add A-record, CNAME-record, MX-record, TXT-record and PTR-record